# Timing for hamotzi

Tags: hamotzi-beracha

After you say hamotzi, how much time do you have before you must eat some bread? I note that *quantities* of food are frequently specified (e.g., at least a kazayit-- an olive's worth, etc.). Are times also specified? My research produced no answer.

Comment: You don't have to eat a kezayit after saying hamotzi.

Answer (score 3):

There  are three different issues here.

1) Time difference between saying a blessing over food (not just hamotzi) and eating that food.

2) Quantity of food and time in which it is consumed to need a blessing afterwards (not just bread)

3) Amount of bread over which it is necessary to say the blessing on the ritual washing of hands.

---

1) The [Kitzur Shulchan Oruch 50 (5)](http://yonanewman.org/kizzur/kizzur50.html) says in this extract:

> One shouldn't hesitate more than momentarily (note i) between
>   (making) the blessing and eating (the food). Even while chewing,  it
>   is forbidden to make any interruptions until one swallows. An
>   interruption by speaking, between the blessing and eating,  about
>   matters not related to the food, requires repeating the blessing. 
>   However, if he waited in silence,  he does not need to go back and
>   (again) bless.  Waiting that's required for the eating isn't
>   considered an interruption at all.
>
> Note i) The time it takes to say the words ''Shalom Alecha Rebbi''
>   (Mishna Berurah 487:4), or according to the Pri Megadim ''Shalom
>   Alecha Rebbi U'Moree.''

2) See the [Star K article](https://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/4105/kzayis-a-guide-to-halachic-food-measurements/) where it says:

> K’zayis Measurement – 1.27 fl. oz. (38 ml) – If one eats a k’zayis of
>   bread, he must recite birchas hamazon. Similarly, if one eats a
>   k’zayis of any other food a brocha acharona must be recited.
>
> An after-brocha is only recited if one eats a k’zayis in the amount of
>   time known as k’dei achilas pras. This means, to recite Birchas
>   hamazon or a bracha acharona  one has to have eaten a k’zayis ideally
>   within a two minute span (b’dieved within a four minute span). The
>   same applies to fulfilling various mitzvos (e.g., achilas matzah).

3) From the same Star K article:

> When washing before eating bread, one recites the brocha of Al
>   Nitilas Yadayim only if one intends to eat a k’beitzah of bread (= Two
>   k’zayisim, 2.53 fl. oz. (75 ml) ).

This answer only starts the subject. Study more and CYLOR.

Comment: Re note i) (under #1), in "metrics" about how many seconds is that?

Comment: I timed myself saying the words - I would say between one and two seconds.

Comment: You sound like a typical "yeshivish yid". You talk too quickly ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are times involved as well. For example, [HaMotzi Richard B. Aiken](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/halacha-lmaaseh/hamotzi/) specifies.

> Wash the One-Time Method and say ha’motzi on bread made of the Five
>   Grains (wheat, rye, oats, barley, or spelt), even if you will not eat
>   at least 1.3 fl. oz. (39 ml, or 1/6 cup) within four minutes.
>
> Note: Say the blessing al netilat yadayim on washing hands ONLY if you
>   will eat at least 1.9. fl. oz. (56 ml) of bread within four minutes.

The bracha rishona applies even for a *mashehu* (any amount). The specification of a particular amount (kazayis) applies only for how much is required in order that one is to say the *birkas hamazon*. The *bracha rishona* statement applies to any food item as explained by [Rav Shlomo Aviner](http://www.ravaviner.com/). As an example

> Q: Does one recite a blessing on chewing gum?
>
> A: Yes, since a blessing before eating does not require a minimal
>   amount (Mishnah Berurah 210:1), one benefits from the sweetness, and
>   it reaches one's stomach (Shut Yabia Omer 7:33 #2.  Although the book
>   Bikdushato Shel Aharon [Volume 1 p. 162, 186] relates that when the
>   Chafetz Chaim and the Belzer Rebbe - Ha-Rav Aharon Rokeach - met in a
>   Rabbinical conference in Warsaw, the Belzer Rebbe poured the Chafetz
>   Chaim a glass of wine and said: Here, we arrived at the minimal
>   amount.  The Chafetz Chaim immediately understood that the Rebbe meant
>   for the blessing preceding the drinking, and was surprised!  The
>   Chafetz Chaim said that this is the position of the Kol Bo [brought in
>   the Beit Yosef, Orach Chaim #210], and apologized, saying that if he
>   had known that there are those who follow it, he would have included
>   it in the Mishnah Berurah!  Only those who are the most particular,
>   however, follow this ruling).

Since it applies to the smallest amount of food, there is no time requirement in which the eating must take place. A time requirement only exists if there is a minimum amount of food mentioned (as with *birkat hamazon* or other *bracha acharona*.)

Comment: Are you saying when you say a blessing on bread you must consume bread within kdai achilas pras?

Comment: @DoubleAA When you get the bread the shiur must be eaten within kdai achilas pras

Comment: What shiur are you talking about?

Comment: I believe 4 minutes is only the Chabad interpretation of  kdei achilat prat.  Halachic opinions vary between 3 and 9 minutes.  Still, at least that's SOME time guidance.  Thanks.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi It's 'pras' not 'prat'

Comment: @DoubleAA I got bracha rishona wrong typing too fast have to rewrite it or delete it once I get home.

Comment: @ Double AA:  You are right -- אכילת פרס  ; sorry.